# “swipe gesture” also registering as touchesBegan touch (used For Player waypoint), How Do You Separate Them, Make Them Independent Of Each Other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

“swipe gesture” also registering as touchesBegan touch (used For Player waypoint), How Do You separate them, make them independent of each other?

From JPZN_ViewController.m //Interface Builder Swipe Gesture

```
-(IBAction)switchGuns:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"line 99 of JPZN_ViewController.m - Gesture SWIPE Recognized");

    [self.scene switchWeapons];
    }
```

From JPZN_GameScene.m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    defaultPlayer.targetLocation = [touch locationInNode:defaultPlayer.hero.parent];
    BOOL wantsAttack = NO;

    if (defaultPlayer.targetLocation.x < 192 || defaultPlayer.targetLocation.x > 2240      || defaultPlayer.targetLocation.y < 192 || defaultPlayer.targetLocation.y > 2240) {
    defaultPlayer.fireAction = wantsAttack;
    defaultPlayer.moveRequested = NO;
    }
else {
    defaultPlayer.fireAction = wantsAttack;
    defaultPlayer.moveRequested = !wantsAttack;
    defaultPlayer.movementTouch = touch;
    }
}
```

I've read the Apple Developer Text on Events and Touches,
If there's more code You'd like to see just ask,
but these are the two methods linked to the gesture and the waypoint creation.
Thanks.

-update More Info.
the 1st touch of the left to right swipe gesture from the IB (interface builder) is also registering as a touch (in my game scene) that creates a waypoint for the player to walk to. I want to disregard the 1st touch of the gesture, separate the swipe touch, from the waypoint touch.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Should you decide to stay, I hope you'll change the way you ask questions, because I can't even read this. The title is too long, the capitalisation is annoying, and in the end I have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: I Don't Need Your Help.
Amadan

Comment: I'm also struggling to understand...the app is doing something with touches, but also has a swipe gr, and the two are interfering with each other?  Can you show the gr code?

Comment: danh,
the GameScene.m uses "touchesBegan" to move the player,
the swipe gr is an IB (interface builder) gesture.

The "touchesBegan" needs To reject the swipe gestures 1st touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `delaysTouchesBegan` to `YES` for the gesture recognizer.  If the gesture recognizer is loaded from a xib or storyboard, you can set it there:

[image: checkbox for delaysTouchesBegan]

Comment: rob mayoff!,
Ah Man Almost,
State Enabled,
But instead of Behavior, Mine Says Events,
Canceled in View,
Delayed Begin,
Delayed End,

seems like the right track though,

Comment: rob!!!, I checked Delayed Begin, and am getting the right result.
When I touch it's a waypoint, when I Swipe it's No Longer using the touch as a waypoint, but I can touch right after and it responds as a waypoint!!!
Until Otherwise Noted, This Is Answered!!!